# Why am I not able to update account record using Name field?

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

As I have research we can update the record based on either **External Id** or **Indexed** field.

Account object has Name field with an Indexed attribute.

[image]

```
Id accountId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // 15 Char Account record id 

// Retrive acccount record based on Id.
Account acc = [Select Id, Name from Account where Id =: accountId];

// Update account record.
acc.Site = 'www.google.com';

// Retrive Name SobjectField.
Schema.SObjectField NameField = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('Name');

// Upsert record based on name field.
Database.upsert(acc, NameField, true);
```

> Note: Here I am passing Name field for update account record.

I am getting an error.

---

> System.SObjectException: Invalid field for upsert, must be an External
>   Id custom or standard indexed field: Name

---

I have passed standard Name field for upsert still it was giving error which said that pass standard Name field.

I am not able to figure it out where is the issue.
anyone has any Idea?
Why am I not able to update account record using Name field?

Comment: AFAIK know upsert can be done using External Id's only which are indexed automatically by Salesforce. (CaseNumber might be an exception to it)

Comment: I think the same as Manjit: the field must an external Id; having an index isn't enough in itself. If there is some documentation that says otherwise please provide a link to it in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For upsert calls important thing is providing a **unique** Id, even an externalId field which is not unique will result an error. [Check following question asked before.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27266/what-is-the-use-of-external-id-field-not-unique) So in your case, since Name field is not unique, it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your response but, I have one doubt. I can do upsert contact based on the email field even if an email is not a unique field.

Comment: @Chintan Email field of Contact is an Idlookup field. IdLookup fields can be used for upsert calls. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm

Comment: So we can only use External Id or IdLookup fields for the upsert records right?

Comment: @Chintan Yes, with one addition, External Id should be unique otherwise it will return error.