# Record with duplicate external id was inserted through bulk API upsert

Tags: bulk-api, upsert, externalid

1. I have Account with user id as external id.
2. I have a record of Account with user id `123` created 2 months ago.
3. I have an upsert job created through bulk API yesterday with user id as `externalIdFieldName`. It was trying to upsert Account with user id `123` and all the other fields.
4. It turns out that another Account with user id `123` was created by the upsert job

Question: why another Account was created instead of updating the old record with user id `123`?
From my understanding, the upsert job will lookup the records with the external id. If it find one matching, it will be updated; otherwise, a new record will be created.

So in this circumstances, why a duplicate record could be created?

Code to create Bulk upsert job:

```
$params = array(
    "externalIdFieldName" => 'User_ID__c',
    "object" => 'Account',
    "operation" => 'upsert'
);
$path = "/services/data/v41.0/jobs/ingest";
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$encodedParams = json_encode($params);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$encodedParams);
// url will be look like csxx.salesforce.com/services/data/v41.0/jobs/ingest
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $this->host . $path);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->connectTimeout/1000);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$header = array('Content-type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer '. $this->sessionId);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
data = curl_exec($c);
```

Comment: Is the External Id set to case-sensitive or case-insensitive? Do the values you're representing as `123` differ in case?

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks for asking. The external id only contains digits. Does the case sensitivity still matter?

Comment: Can you share the code you use to create the Bulk API job?

Comment: @DavidReed I was referencing [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/walkthrough_upsert.htm) to create Bulk API job. I'm using php so it's basically setting the cUrl opts. It's posted in the question.

Comment: is externalId defined as unique?

Comment: @cropredy I believe it's not, but why it makes sense that upsert can create a duplicate one?

Comment: vera - a relevant post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27266/what-is-the-use-of-external-id-field-not-unique